# How to send data from a web server to another application

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, discord.js

So kind of general question but i'm struggling to find answers on how to do this. I have a SQLite database file on my web server, how would I go about letting my discord bot application look at that data when it's not on the web server?

Comment: The two most common routes would be to either (a) use a proper database server and have your bot query directly against that (generally not a terribly great idea as far as security goes, but doable), or (b) build an API that your bot lodges HTTP requests against, which then queries the database on behalf of the bot and returns the data in a format the bot can then parse and process as it sees fit.

Comment: In any event, your question is *way* too broad for Stack Overflow and is likely to be closed. Please edit it to ask a specific, answerable technical issue and to better conform to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It sounds like you need a messaging system:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using node.js, use the built in `http` module. Here is an example of how that would work using `Promises`:

```js
(
    await new Promise(resolve =>
        require('https')
        .get('https://www.example.com', res => res.on('data', resolve))
    )
)
.toString()
```

If you are in the browser, use `fetch`:

```
await (await fetch('https://enable-cors.org/')).text()
```

Make sure either of these are in an `async` context, or there will be an error. Here is an example of async context:

```
async function go() {
    //async code
}
go();
```

or

```
<script type='module'>
//async code
</script>
```

Comment: So i would just .get lets say https://www.example.com/database.db?

Comment: Yes, but be sure to include `https` for the `https` module and `http` for the `http` module.

Comment: Or you could use a dependency like [node fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) that simplifies that for you :)

Answer (score -1):

If you mean you want one of your application to get data from your SQLite database which lives in a different web server. Take a look at RESTful API, you need to build a web service in your SQLite server which returns data on API calls, and you can make the API calls from the server of your app.